# Disable custom post type links depending on the taxonomy option

Tags: php, custom-post-type

I have a list ([shown as a grid by this plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/advance-post-gridlist-with-custom-filtering-for-visual-composer/8712997)) of Custom Post Types, but I need the ones under one taxonomy value to have a link to the inner page.

**Example:** I have the taxonomy "*example*" with 3 options (*OptionA
 - OptionB
 - OptionC*), but I just want the ones under "OptionB" to have an inner link:

I know there is a solution via css (hiding the links styles), but I would like to keep the whole site clean of css tricks.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality using PHP?

Here is the part of the PHP code that adds the link to the titles:

```
$output .= '<div class="pl-detailcnt">
    <h4 class="pl-title left-txt">';
    if (isset($this->pw_hide_date) && ($this->pw_hide_date=='off')){
    $output .= '<span class="pl-date">'. get_the_date($this->pw_date_format).'</span>';
    }
    $output .= '<a href="'. $post->link .'" target="'. $this->pw_link_target  .'">'. get_the_title().'</a></h4>
    </div>';
```

Since I can't add the whole code (max characters exceeded) as @Dontfeedthecode suggested, here it goes: http://ideone.com/HeVfny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION (using a bit of JQuery).**

**First step:** 
Add the term-slug as a CSS class, so I can distinguish between classes for customize it later with JQuery.

```
<div class="add_your_random_class_here '.$term->slug.'">
```

**Second Step:** 
Disable the links that have the term-slug class created.

```
<script>
 jQuery(function() {
jQuery('.here-goes-your-new-based-slug-class').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
});
</script>
```

Any improvement will be welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can query for taxonomies for the post then check to see if your custom post type is in the array it returns:

```
$post_types = get_object_taxonomies( $post );

if( in_array( 'your taxonomy name', $post_types )) {
    // Show link
}
```

Comment: I've tried, but as it also querys by $post_orders, and I dont know how to add both, it breaks the page.

Comment: Can you paste the whole file so I have a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: Well, there is a large file, but I'll edit my post so you'll be able to see it.